# Unable to execute selenium-side-runner using crontab (MAC)

Tags: selenium, cron

Got a problem executing selenium-side-runner via crontab, installed via npm.

Following command has been executed.

```
1. npm install -g selenium-side-runner
2. npm install -g chromedriver
```

I was able to run the selenium-side-runner via terminal directly by calling.

"selenium-side-runner (path to .side file)"

***when trying to create a crontab. using the following commands.***

```
"0 5 * * * selenium-side-runner <path to .side file> >> /tmp/sel.log 2>&1"
OR
"0 5 * * * /usr/local/bin/selenium-side-runner <path to .side file> >> /tmp/sel.log 2>&1"
```

Still got no LUCK on the following snippet.

NOTE: selenium-side-runner can be found under /usr/local/bin --
I checked it out using "which selenium-side-runner"
I also checked that $PATH and /usr/local/bin is there.

FF Error message received under "sel.log"

```
1. command not found
2. No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me out on this please.....

Comment: cron runs with a different environment than your regular session is using